# Website source control and big setup binaries

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, tfs, download

Many times website developers need to handle the download of heavy *.exe or *.msi setup files from their website. Today this involves complex hotlinking protection and multiple binaries version management.

The question is: does it worth to include these heavy binaries (in our case ~300MB) to website source control? Is there any workaround to fully test the download locally without including these file - that will never change - to Team Foundation Server source control?

Comment: Web site "project" or web application project?

Comment: @John: I am talking of an ASP.NET MVC 3 application project.

Answer (score 0):

if the binaries are external you have two options:

**option 1:** I prefer to include them in your solution.

**option 2:** you can create a team project called "Common Binaries" and make it a shared resource of all common binaries.

Comment: I don't see the benefit of moving the same files do a different team project, they are always hundreds of megabites of never changing binaries added to source control...